# How does the following Python line exactly work? d.setdefault(c.suit, PokerHand()).add_card(c)

Tags: python

It's the last piece of code I cannot grasp from the official solution for the `PokerHand` exercise from ThinkPython book:

[card.py](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/code/Card.py)

and

[PokerHandSoln.py](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/code/PokerHandSoln.py)

```
def has_straightflush(self):
    """Checks whether this hand has a straight flush.

    Better algorithm (in the sense of being more demonstrably
    correct).
    """
    # partition the hand by suit and check each
    # sub-hand for a straight
    d = {}
    for c in self.cards:
        d.setdefault(c.suit, PokerHand()).add_card(c)
        print '\n', c.suit, '\n', d[c.suit]
    wait = raw_input()

    # see if any of the partitioned hands has a straight
    for hand in d.values():
        if len(hand.cards) < 5:
            continue
        hand.make_histograms()
        if hand.has_straight():
            return True
    return False
```

print and wait are mine to try to figure out what it does.

I wrote my own solution but of course it's different from the author's one.
My solution works after some debugging, but I'm studying the author's official solution. Self-starter and Python newbie here

I got how `setdefault` works, but not the `add_card` method.
The `add_card` method is a class method that executes an `append()` operation.
The values of the dictionary are class objects.

So is that code just executing the method proper of that class, on an object of that class? It's a very concise code expression and a bit difficult to grasp for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dict.setdefault()` *returns* the value for the given key (having optionally set a default value first, if the key is missing).

The `d.setdefault(c.suit, PokerHand()).add_card(c)` expression makes sure there is a value for the `c.suit` key, and returns that. The default is `PokerHand()`, an instance of a class that defines the `add_card()` method.

Split it out into two statements, if that makes it easier to read:

```
hand_for_suit = d.setdefault(c.suit, PokerHand())
hand_for_suit.add_card(c)
```

In the end you have grouped the cards into hands by suit; all diamond cards, all hearts, all clubs and all spades each grouped into a separate `PokerHand()` instance. This makes it easier to test if there is a *straight flush*, an ordered series of cards in the same suit.

Comment: Thank you. I think I was understanding it better at the same time I was writing my question (writing helps clear the mind), but your split definitely helped. Unfortunately it looks like I cannot vote your answer as I'm new on the site.